# Why am I seeing some garbage bytes at the serial console login?

Tags: serial, uart, serial-console

When I log into my serial console using `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`, I see some garbage in the output:

```
��
Arch Linux 3.6.11-10-ARCH+ (ttyAMA0)

raspberry login: root
�Password: 
Login incorrect

raspberry login: root
Password:
```

These question marks are the `FD` bytes (hexadecimal) according to the hardcopy I made using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd> and `F8` according to the screen log (`screen -L`). Observe that only the first *Password* line has the question mark, subsequent password prompts do not have that byte.

How can I stop these question marks from appearing? Do I need to change the tty settings or specify other `screen` parameters?

The getty process that is started by systemd has the following command:

```
/sbin/agetty --noclear ttyAMA0 115200 linux
```

I am using a USB device for hooking up the serial line:

> 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port

Comment: Prolific is well known for buggy hardware, did you try any other USB-Serial adapter?

Comment: @lenik I haven't got another. This adapter works fine with an other device (router), it only shows issues with this configuration. It looks like a software issue to me. Have you tried the serial console yourself? (btw, I tested with other baud rates too, it makes no difference)

Comment: I would say that is normal. Have seen a lot of network devices giving out weird characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the well known bug of the spurious character when the serial port is opened.  I don't remember the details, something to do with the TX line dropping for an instant so signalling a spurious start bit.  From memory it is a bug in the Raspberry Pi Linux driver.  I don't know why it hasn't been fixed, it has been commented on for several years.

As I say the character happens on port open,  e.g.

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR);
```

will cause the error.

The work around is to ignore the first byte and not to needlessly close/open the serial port.

Comment: What about `Password`? The behavior is so deterministic that it looks like a special control character which somehow does not get handled?

Comment: I'd have to connect a serial cable and have a look while a Pi is booting.  Of course serial data can be corrupted for all sorts of additional reasons.  In my case it's usually because I've forgotten to connect the grounds.  Give me an hour or so and I'll have a look.

Comment: @Lekensteyn  A link to a boot up [webm](http://abyz.co.uk/videos/spurious.webm).  I only see spurious characters pretty much where I'd expect, the times the port is opened, apart from one character early on which was probably just corrupt.

Comment: Must be a bug in the RPi driver, the wires were already connected so any bit flipping happens because the driver is in a wrong state. No time to look into the driver source code, but thanks for your answer!

Comment: _"ignore the first byte"_ means ignoring one character, Yet the OP defines clearly this goes beyond the first byte...

Comment: @Tyson You are quite right.  There are several issues. Opening the port does produce spurious characters.  I'd expect one per open.  I haven't the hardware (or inclination) to see if a single open can generate more than one spurious character.  However, a software engineer should write defensive software.  Spurious data on a serial link must be expected.  Serial messages need to be checksummed so that erroneous data can be discarded.